# Each time it automaticaly login the user, it displaying first the connection Page

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to connect user automatically so fast that he doesn't get to see the login page ?
Because each time when i test my app and open it , and the user is already connected it still show the login page, even if it's not long.

Here my code :

```
  handleFirebaseSignIn(FirebaseUser user) async {
    if (user != null) {
      await getFirebaseUserInFirestore();
      setState(() {
        isAuth = true;
      });

    } else {
      setState(() {
        isAuth = false;
      });
    }
  }

 @override void initState() {
        super.initState();
        pageController = PageController();

        googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((account) {}, onError: (err) {
          print('Error signing in: $err');
        });

        googleSignIn
            .signInSilently(suppressErrors: false)
            .then((account) {})
            .catchError((err) {
          print('Error signing in: $err');
        });

        auth.currentUser().then((user) async {
          handleFirebaseSignIn(user);
        }, onError: (err) {
          print('Error signing in: $err');
        });

        auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen((user) async {
          handleFirebaseSignIn(user);
        }, onError: (err) {
          print('Error signing in: $err');
        });

      }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    if (isAuth) {
      return buildAuthScreen();  //Show the page when the user is logged 
    } else if (isRegister) {
      return buildSignUpUnAuthScreen(); // Show the page when the user is unlogged (scaffold)
    } else {
      setState(() {
        this.pageIndex = 0;
      });
      return buildSignInUnAuthScreen(); // Show the page when the user is unlogged (scaffold)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes a bit time to load the data so Login page is shown first.

You should add a splashcreen so the user doesn't see these things happen in the background.